# How to add textfield in Layout when i use Custom ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

I am creating a chat app. I have to create a field for Send Sms.. But when i insert textField, It comes like this,

[image: SCREEN SHOTS]

here is my layout file

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:padding="5dp" >
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/logo"
>     android:layout_width="50px"
>     android:layout_height="50px"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:src="@drawable/windowsmobile_logo" />
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/label"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/logo"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
>     android:text="@+id/label"
>     android:textSize="30px" />
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Here is my Custom Adapter

```
      @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mobile, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values[position];

    System.out.println(s);

    if (s.equals("WindowsMobile")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.windowsmobile_logo);
    } else if (s.equals("iOS")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ios_logo);
    } else if (s.equals("Blackberry")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackberry_logo);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_logo);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

I got this example in  [this website](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/)

Hope you Understand my Problem ! Any help is Appreciated !!

Comment: @BalaKrishna read a bit of documentaion

Comment: I asked Here Because i cant understand that clearly..

Answer (score 0):

Got the Solution.. Got to know How Silly I am.. Jus Create a Listview inside a Relative layout and Link an Adapter to it !! Example

```
mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);
listAdapter.add( "Ceres" );
listAdapter.add( "Pluto" );
listAdapter.add( "Haumea" );
listAdapter.add( "Makemake" );
listAdapter.add( "Eris" );
 mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
```

Simple and Superb.. In that relative layout  Insert the TextField and Button.. Got solved :) 
 @blackbelt Thanks